# Adding Spaces in a Ciphertext Conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am trying to convert plaintext to ciphertext:

> plaintext = 'defend the east wall of the castle'
>
> ciphertext: 'efgfoe uif fbtu xbmm pg uif dbtumf'

```
p = plaintext.split(' ')
for i in p:
    i2=[i]
    for word in i2:
        for letter in word:
            inc=ord(letter)+1
            print(chr(inc),end='')
```

The solution I am getting is:

```
efgfoeuiffbtuxbmmpguifdbtumf
```

How can I include the relevant spaces as plaintext?

Like : 'efgfoe uif fbtu xbmm pg uif dbtumf'

Comment: oh, you're splitting your words, but that removes the spaces and you don't know the positions unless you issue a space outside the inner loop for instance. Or don't split at all, and check the character code before "encrypting"

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
plaintext = 'defend the east wall of the castle'
p = plaintext.split(' ')
wholecipher=[]
for word in p:
    word_cipher=''
    for letter in word:
        inc=ord(letter)+1
        word_cipher += chr(inc)
    wholecipher.append(word_cipher)

print(' '.join(wholecipher))
```

Comment: @Student  let me know where you got confused

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Its alright.  If you have got the solution select the answer by clicking right button and close the thread . Thanks